# The Entry fields are not being updated using user-defined modules

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a master program in python3 that calls sub-programs via modules. This works fine, except that my modules don't update the Entry fields when changes are made elsewhere within the module. The Module shows that values are put in the correct place, but the window isn't updated. Here is an example of the master program:-

```
# test - master

from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.title("Test for the update problem")

import changeEntryfield

changeEntryfield.fun() # call to function inside module

root.mainloop()

# end of master program
```

And here is the module that is called (stored as "changeEntryfield.py"):-

```
def fun():

    import tkinter 


    win=tkinter.Tk() # start a window

    g3=tkinter.StringVar()

    g3.set("text")

    a="something"

    field=tkinter.Entry(win,width=10,textvariable=g3)
    field.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='W',padx=5,pady=5)

    grpslab3=tkinter.Label(win,text="The Field is: ")
    grpslab3.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='W',padx=5,pady=5)

    # now do changes to field value

    g3.set(a)
    print ("1. In Entry, field = ",field['textvariable'])

    field['textvariable']=g3.get()
    print ("2. In Entry, field = ",field['textvariable'])

    field.config(textvariable=g3.get())
    print ("3. In Entry, field = ",field['textvariable'])

    field['textvariable']=a
    print ("4. In Entry, field = ",field['textvariable'])

    win.mainloop()

# end of module
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: All of your updates happen within a single frame before you've begun the `mainloop` of your `win` window. How do you expect the changes to show up on the screen? I'm also inclined to suspect that all of your changes to `textvariable` are invalid since they're not providing a `StringVar` (but rather a string).

Comment: Does win.mainloop return so root.mainloop is called?

Comment: The module contains "g3=tkinter.StringVar()", so your point about StringVar is answered. Thanks for the suggestion about "return". See my final fix for this below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter isn't designed to work this way. A complete program should only ever have a single instance of `Tk` at one time. You should create instances of `Toplevel` in your sub-programs.

Comment: Replacing the line "win=tkinter.Tk() # start a window" with "win=tkinter.Toplevel(None) # start window", and replacing the "win.mainloop()" with "return" at the end of the module solves the problem. I should have thought of that earlier. Thanks for this.